# calculate largest and smallest eigenvalues

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, svd

I need to calculate the condition number of a dense matrix A many times(with some changes to A in each time), where the condition number define to be the largest eigenvalue of A divided by the smallest eigenvalue.
A is in an order of about 1000x5000 and performing

```
np.linalg.svd(A, compute_uv=False)
```

take approximately 0.6 seconds

on the other hand

```
scipy.sparse.linalg.svds(A, 1, which='SM')
```

and

```
scipy.sparse.linalg.svds(A, 1)
```

does not converge due to the density of A (I think)

there is any way to compute only the largest and smallest eigenvalues of a dense matrix? or a way to manipulate A in such a way in which I could use scipy.sparse.linalg.svds without changing the eigenvalues?

Comment: What are you using the condition number for?  There are some other ways to define it that may be quicker to calculate.

Comment: I use it to subsample earthquake data to solve the set of equation Ax = d where d is the data and A depends on the data selection. my goal is to subsample the data in a way that the condition number will be minimal.

Comment: If you're open to more general solutions to that problem please update the question with what your overall goal is, and why you want the smallest condition number.  That will open up some other possible solutions.

Comment: Otherwise using `cond(A, p='fro')` has sped up some algorithms I've implemented (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cond.html).

Comment: I can't use `cond(A, p='fro')` or any other option in cond() except p=None because it is using numpy.linalg.inv which enforce my matrix A to be square @user2699

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize that.  I don't think there's an easy answer to this then - at least not one that numpy provides by default.